# Find Method Returning False

Tags: php, cakephp-2.4

I am trying to execute a find in my script, but I believe my condition is returning false. I am trying to execute a find and pull all records that match the given value in my `$data` variable. I have tried to compare the `BranchLicense.RegionCode` to `$data` but no luck. I have also tried to compare it the `_Session['Auth']['User']['region_code']`. The `$data` variable is returning the correct value but the script does not return the proper records. What am I doing wrong here? Here is my code.

```
//echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION); echo '</pre>';
//$this->loadModel('AuthAcl.Users');

$data = $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['region_code'];

//$data = $this->Users->find('all');

$new = $this->BranchLicense->find('all', array(
'conditions' => array('BranchLicense.RegionCode' == $data)));
die(debug($new));

$this->layout = 'default';

//$this->set('branchLicenses', $this->BranchLicense->find('all', array(
//'conditions' => array('BranchLicense.RegionCode' === '$data'))));
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the query that the find is generating, and running that on the database manually?  You can get cake to output the queries it's going through by setting debug to be 2 in /app/Config/core.php and adding echo $this->element('sql_dump'); to the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows-

```
   $new = $this->BranchLicense->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('BranchLicense.RegionCode' => $data)));
    die(debug($new));
```

Comment: Thanks!! I tried that earlier but it didn't work!! Oh well! Thanks again!